# Retrieving an object in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode

I am trying to retrieve an object as a key in a Map when I have changed an instance variable of it. As far as I am concerned, when I search a key object in a Map structure, it should come up when hashCode method returns the same value as initially. However, based on the following code, I cannot retrieve the object through method get() having altered the value of the variable weight:

```
public class Car  implements Comparable<Car> {

 int weight;
 String name;

 public Car(int w, String n) {
    weight=w;
    name=n;
 }

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Car){
        Car d = (Car)o;
        return ((d.name.equals(name)) && (d.weight==weight));
    }
    return false;

}

public int hashCode(){
    return weight/2 + 17;
}

public String toString(){
    return "I am " +name+ " with weight: "+weight;
}


public int compareTo(Car d){
    if(this.weight>d.weight)
        return 1;
    else if(this.weight<d.weight)
        return -1;
    else
        return this.name.compareTo(d.name);
}

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car d1 = new Car(107, "a");
    Car d2 = new Car(110, "b");
    Car d3 = new Car(110, "c");
    Car d4 = new Car(107, "a");

    Map<Car, Integer> m = new HashMap<Car, Integer>();
    m.put(d1, 1);
    m.put(d2, 2);
    m.put(d3, 3);
    m.put(d4, 16);

    System.out.println(m.get(d1).toString());
    d1.weight = 34;
    System.out.println(m.get(new Car(34, "a")));

    for(Map.Entry<Car, Integer> me : m.entrySet())
        System.out.println(me.getKey().toString() + " value: " +me.getValue());

}
```

The output is:

```
16

null

I am a with weight: 34 16

I am c with weight: 110 3

I am b with weight: 110 2
```

However, if I do not change the value of weight (omit the line: `d1.weight = 34;` ), merely using the line of code:

```
System.out.println(m.get(new Car(107, "a")));
```

the output is:

```
16

16

I am a with weight: 107 value: 16

I am c with weight: 110 value: 3

I am b with weight: 110 value: 2
```

It finds actually the object. Does it come to the expected output in both ways, or should it also in the first version have found and retrieved the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be very careful when storing mutable objects as keys in a hashtable.  The hash code is computed only once, on object insert.  If you later change the object in a way that affects its hash code, it is very likely that it will be impossible to find.

You need to remove the object and reinsert it whenever such a change is made.

Comment: In particular, the OP's belief that it's just the `hashCode` that must stay the same is false: the `equals` results must remain the same as well.  (But in general, you should only use immutable objects as map keys.)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(m.get(new Car(34, "a")));
```

Your map returns null here because it does not contain a key object with hashcode 34.

However with

```
System.out.println(m.get(new Car(107, "a")));
```

your map does return an object because it does contain a key object with hashcode 70.